# The name of the Golden egg that is filled with Ananda

Tags: scripture, philosophy, lokas, consciousness

When the consciousness has so to speak - gone beyond, all together beyond the temporal realm of the phenomenal and gone beyond altogether beyond the realm of Nirguna Brahman and enters the realm of the Golden womb the Golden egg that is filled with Ananda. 
What is the given name of this place in Hindu Mythology - Philosophy ?

Comment: There is no 'realm beyond' Nirguna Brahman. Nirguna Brahman is the ultimate Reality. Not sure where you are getting this term 'golden bliss'.

Comment: Which book you're reading ? @Frank

Comment: While asking question, please give reference that where did you read/know about it from. It'll help us to give proper answer. @Frank

Comment: It would be better if you write question with some details like what scriptures you're reading and what you want to know i.e your questions are not clear usually. Make the title more specific.

Comment: The golden egg is Hiranyagarbha and it is not beyond Nirguna Brahman. Hiranyagarbha is the starting point, rather commencing point of the Brahmanda.

Answer (score 2):

**Absolute bliss is attained within "I" or "Me" (viz. *Atma*)**.
Based on Gita, many people refer it as *NijAnanda* (bliss within self).

> BG 14.27 - For **'I' am the Abode of Brahman** - the indestructible and immutable, the eternal, the Dharma and **absolute Bliss**.

Possibly you meant [Hiranyagarbha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiranyagarbha), by the "golden egg", from where the whole universe manifests and merges back.
Of course, we can keep naming such 'realms' as the beyond of beyond of beyond of beyond ... But until we 'name' it, it's describable and hence it cannot move out of the temporal realm.

Comment: Hiranya Garbha=Golden egg/womb.

Comment: @iammilind Hiranyagarbha is the name of the place and it is filled with bliss and is the home of Brahman. So Nirguna Brahman is born from Hiranyagarbha and returns back to Hiranyagarbha, so Hiranyagarbha is the source of Brahman and beyond Nirguna Brahman ?

Comment: "*So Nirguna Brahman is born from Hiranyagarbha and returns back to Hiranyagarbha*" @Frank, No. *Nirguna* means "quality-less". So it's referred as unborn & eternal. Actually we just name it "Nirguna Brahman" to be able to refer it. Some people call it "nothingness" & Buddhist call it "*Shunya*" or void. 'Nothing' existed before something (e.g. golden egg) is born & 'nothing' still exists when that something becomes everything & 'nothing' will exist after everything is destroyed. This 'nothing' is *nirguna Brahman* or 'that' or 'Me'.